# Is there a big difference between ros2foxy and ros2humble?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw a smart cart for ROS2, which happens to be the direction I want to learn, so I want to buy it. However, the official system for the cart is ROS2foxy, and I am learning ROS2humble, which is causing me a lot of frustration. I would like some advice from you guys. Is there a big difference between foxy and humble, and should I buy it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/418051/is-there-a-big-difference-between-ros2foxy-and-ros2humble?/) by [xudadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/166967/xudadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2023-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-08-02**:
It would be better if the title of your post was the question you are asking. You can edit it using the little "edit" link just under the existing title.

**Comment by [xudadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/166967/xudadi/) on 2023-08-03**:
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of robotics covers a very large number of technical areas (mechanical, electrical, software, algorithms), so I would say the decision to buy a robot with ros2 installed depends which aspects of robotics you are interested in right now. If you have a halfway decent desktop/laptop computer, you can definitely do most of your learning/exploring in the software simulator. It's not as satisfying as making a real object move, but the crashes are also less expensive.

The difference between foxy and humble is that humble will have more features implemented and a lot of bugs fixed. However, *most* of the concepts & software APIs in the two versions should be the same.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2023-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't really matter which you learn, although Humble is current and Foxy is not. There are specific differences that will complicate using Foxy or Humble but for learning the concepts and getting experience, it's no matter.

Regarding if you should buy a smart cart or not....?? Not if it's this one. `https://www.tackeria.com/contents/en-us/p3408_Smart_Cart_with_Flat_Free_Tires__.html`

You can get a lot of learning using Gazebo/RVIZ with only your PC and HW.  On the other end of the learning spectrum is building your own robot from scratch and developing your own HW drivers in ROS and making it work. Buying pre-made HW that already has it's own drivers and functioning ROS build seems like the worst way to learn it. You won't be forced into the details that really matter. You'll have a toy and platform for further development but may not learn the basics at all.

I say create your own simulated custom robot using the Tutorials and once you understand how ROS works, you then think again about HW.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2023-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1